# How does an electromagnetic wave behave when it enters a medium with refractive index less than unity?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, refraction

From what I am able to find, the phase velosity of the wave exceeds c, but the group velosity remains less than c. However, why does the wave form wavepackets after entering a medium with refractive index less than unity?

Comment: If you're thinking about what happens to the leading edge of a light beam, you're already thinking in wave-packets (because a true single-frequency wave would not just "start")